# How can I select children of html tag in html page?

Tags: jquery

**My html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <img class="brand" src="../../Content/Image/UzNno.jpg" width="38" height="19" alt="Atish" />
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
                        <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar-inner -->
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="../../Scripts/Tree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My js File**

```
var elements = $("html").children();

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    alert(elements[i]);
}
```

**Output**

```
[object HTMLScriptElement]
[object HTMLScriptElement]
[object HTMLHeadElement]
[object HTMLBodyElement]
```

**I want**

```
[object HTMLHeadElement]
[object HTMLBodyElement]
```

Comment: [Don't use alert for debugging](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: Maybe other JS scripts add some HTMLScriptElements to <html>?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there are much better ways.  We could help if you would explain the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: maybe he wants to get the attribute of the set elements?

Comment: I need to save children of html into the elements.

Comment: As Juhana said alert is bad for debugging. I usually use console.log and have a look at the output in the console. At least in Chrome you can analyze the whole object structure, which is helpful in most cases.

Comment: Unfortunately *"I need to save children of html into the elements"* is a little ambiguous... What elements are being saved into?

Comment: ok @HiTechMagic I want to alert the children of html tag.

Comment: Down voter care to comment.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor I'm wondering if one of the comments already is by the downvoter. Note that voting is anonymous

Comment: OK. Answer updated. That will only show the child elements.

Comment: I edit my question. Please everybody have a look to it.

Comment: I ran a test and my theory was incorrect about selectors skipping script blocks. Answer deleted.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do it? @HiTechMagic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In answer to your actual question asked:

It works that way because you are iterating the raw DOM hierarchy. That shows all child elements including scripts. Scripts are not necessarily stored where they are declared and this is likely to differ across browsers.

### If you want to ignore the scripts, change your initial selector to:

```
var elements = $("#hello").children(':not(script)');
```

and leave the rest as-is.

Otherwise, please reword your question to explain the overall aim :)

### JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Pv57/

As you wanted the tag names, use tagName (who could have guessed!) :)

### http://jsfiddle.net/6Pv57/1/

Comment: it still doesn't explain how the scripts got there in the first place, however.

Comment: Can I alert it like head and body. not as object HTMLHeadElement. @HiTech Magic

Comment: Phew... please provide a JSFiddle if you can on future questions... saves a lot of scrabbling about :)

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Added back my original explanation... hope that meets with your approval... if not I look forward to your own answer :P

Answer (score 0):

var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;

To select the head...

or you can also use element selector like

```
$("head")
//for example:
alert($("head").html()); //alerts the <head> children
```

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EqR6p/)